# How to add a button to TabItem? Not XAML

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm just trying to add a simple button to tabitem in order to display in the design mode and execution see the code below:

```
public class MyTabItem :TabItem
{

    public MyTabItem()
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) || !DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Width = 300;
            this.Header = btn;
        }

    }

 }
```

I've search the solution which always suggests to create a user control to add it. Any directions?

thanks

Comment: I tried your code and it creates a TabItem with a button inside the header. What is your question?

Comment: you were right, the problem was that in the constructor it is not adding the button, I put the same code in the setter or our exposed Property and it worked just fine, thanks

Comment: adding unneeded properties to WPF UI elements for this purpose will be really detrimental down the road. Regular CLR properties cannot be used as binding targets and even if you're using DPs you could easily achieve the same using the vanilla WPF `TabItem` with a `HeaderTemplate`. Again, Please reconsider your approach. Every single line of code you write is worsening the scenario more and more.